# Deploying Azure Linux web app with Terraform results in unsupported block error for app_settings

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to deploy a linux web app using Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_app" {
  name                = "pi"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.service_plan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.service_plan.id

  site_config {
  }

  app_settings {
    MYSETTING = "some value"
  }
}
```

I am using provider version 3.89.0 (latest at time of writing)

```
  required_version = ">=1.6.0"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.89.0"
    }
  }
```

I get the following error when I run my terraform script in my Devops piepline;

> Error: Unsupported block type on main.tf line 125, in resource
> "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_app":
> 125:   app_settings {    Blocks of
> type "app_settings" are not expected here.
>
> Did you mean to define
> argument "app_settings"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a
> value.

Unless I'm misreading it, [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app) states that there is such a block. The error is pretty clear and I need to pass in some app_settings values. Does anyone know why I might be having these issues and how I might resolve them?

Thanks.

Comment: I think app settings go before site config {} if I remember rightly Ive not been on Azure for two months

Comment: @Jason thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a go but unfortunately I got the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

app_settings is not a block, its a property. I was declaring it incorrectly. I need to include an equals sign between the property name and the first curly brace.

```
  app_settings = {
    MYSETTING = "some value"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`app_settings` keys need to be string literals.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_app" {
       app_settings {
          "MYSETTING" = "some value"
       }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, app_settings is missing the equals sign, since it is not a block but an attribute. They also don't need to be literals, although I tried it both ways out of curiosity. I have this working in production now. using the answer provided